# BinaryFormatter object graph upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, class-design, binaryformatter

In my object graph, I have something like

```
[Serializable]
public class Dog 
{
     string _name;
}
```

and I have all sorts of lists of Dogs and reference to Dogs.

Since Dog was only animal at the start of the software creation, I didn't have a need for any base class.  Now, that need has emerged and now I would like to have

```
[Serializable]
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public void Bark() { }
}

[Serializable]
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public void DoTheCatStuff() { }
}

[Serializable]
public class Animal 
{
     string _name;
}
```

BUT: when I deserialize OLD archive, I don't have any dogs.  They didn't deserialize from the archive at all.

What I would like is some advice on how to do it.  If I'll need new class hierarchy and manually copy the objects from the old Dog to the new TheDog, fine, but would like to avoid it if possible.

EDIT: Some .NET gurus, WHY don't I have any Dogs?

Comment: I ran a simple test with BinaryFormatter (serialize, modify class definition, deserialize) with the code above and I didn't see any issue. Are you sure the above code is the issue?

Comment: Try adding List<Dog> to the object graph...

Comment: @Daniel, I repeated with List<Dog> but still couldn't repro.

Comment: You got whole list of derived Dogs properly filled?  Despite the fact that you moved its private part into the Animal?

Comment: OK, I get the List<Dog> but the field that was moved (_name) is not populated (i.e. null).

Comment: Is it possible for you to use composition instead of inheritance and maintain the original structure but use another class (e.g. Animal) for the common data and functionality?

Comment: It is possible, and isn't so bad idea, but then I would drop the inheritance concept and go for copy/paste principle.

Comment: It defeats the ease of use of serialization but if this is an ongoing issue maybe consider a separate serialized representation to try to isolate breaking changes between representation and implementation?

Comment: Well, I'll leave this question open hoping that someone will find a way to fill _name with the original value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need an implementation of [ISerializationSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcxzt4w7.aspx) and some [SerializationBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder.aspx) magic. There is a very good discussion of this in an old [MSDN Magazine column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one; my gut instinct is to do this:

I would write an upgrade program that has the old class format that writes it out to the new format, or an intermediate format that you can then comprehend and convert to your new class hierarchy.

Perhaps by deserialising the binary format of the old archive, XML serialize it and then maybe use LinqToXml to create objects in your new hierarchy.

Comment: I am currently doing upgrades in a way that I maintain int _serial in the root of the graph, and do stuff when serial isn't the newest one.  So far (18 months, 10 sites, 20-so upgrades) didn't have a need for external upgrade procedure...

Comment: So is the sub-classing of 'dog' a very recent thing that's caused this problem ?  I'm wondering if some of the 'version tolerant serialization' attributes might help, by adding a callback to handle the value:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I am using .net2.0, and this document says that it doesn't handle VersionAdded attribute.  Anyway, I didn't follow the guidelines from the article and so far didn't have any problems with (de)serialization.

Comment: You need to also be aware that binary serialization looks for exact version matches by default for certain assemblies. For instance I believe that for strong named assemblies, the assembly version must also match. I have run into this problem with trying to store BinarySerialized objects and rehydrating them.

In fact, BinarySerialization was such a problem storing to disk because of versioning issues, I eventually went with a zipped, serialized XML version.

Comment: Did the XML version handles multiple references to the same object?  BinaryFormatter does so.